# SQL Server Analysis - VertiPaqPagingPolicy setting

Tags: ssas

Anyone know how Mode 2 for the setting works? I can not find any documentation.

I want to know where on disc the paging occurs, which dir setting?

It is mentioned here but not much to go on: https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/05/what-happens-when-a-ssas-tabular-model-exceeds-memory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Tabular performance guide](http://aka.ms/ASTabPerf2012):

> 2 is currently not supported. It is mentioned to make it clear it is
> not supported since some blog posts on the Internet say otherwise. If
> supported in the future, this paging policy will allow paging through
> memory mapped files. Dictionaries must remain in memory.

I would not recommend you use mode 2. For sure mode 1 pages to pagefile.sys on whatever drive(s) that is set on. My vague understanding of [memory mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files?) is that you would see I/O against the drive with the DataDir.

Mode 2 is [discontinued](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/analysis-services-backward-compatibility?#discontinued-features-1) in the SQL Server 2017 version.