# Analysis Services Processing Failing

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I am processing (partitional) one of my tables in Analysis Services but it is failing. This partition is around 6M rows. I tried to process other partition which has 5M rows and it succeeded.

Error message is something like:

```
The following system error occurred:  Insufficient quota to complete the requested service.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Tabular Model has exceeded the memory limits, when loading the data in memory. You may need to alter the [paging settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms174514(v=sql.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for the instance.

- Zero (0) is the default.  No paging is allowed.  If memory is
  insufficient, processing fails with an out-of-memory error.  All
  Tabular data is locked in memory
- 1 enables paging to disk using the operating system page file
  (pagefile.sys).  Lock only hash dictionaries in memory, and allow
  Tabular data to exceed total physical memory
- 2 enables paging to disk using memory-mapped files.  Lock only hash dictionaries in memory, and allow Tabular data to exceed total physical memory. This setting has now been [discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55718873/5070440).

The values are taken from this [blog](https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2012/05/what-happens-when-a-ssas-tabular-model-exceeds-memory/) which will give you a good overview

Comment: Thanks. After Retrieveing 6M rows, it then failed. I am thinking that there could be data that is causing this issue. like null values or invalid characters